# Send NSString to another UIViewController gives null

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, nsstring

It is simple, but I really don't know why it always gives me null.

**- FirstViewcontroller:**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    [_tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

        SubViewViewController *viewTwo = [[SubViewViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SubViewViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];


    viewTwo.queryValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.subViewController animated:YES];
}
```

**- SecondViewcontroller.h:**

```
NSString             *queryValue;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *queryValue;
```

**- SecondViewcontroller.m:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"%@", self.queryValue);
}
```

Comment: First of all, you dont have to create instant variables anymore, an NSString property is sufficient. If I were you, I would override setQueryValue method, put a breakpoint there and see where the problem lies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code you are doing wrong you should initialize the viewController which you are pushing to the navigationController, you are initializing `viewTo` but you are pushing `self.subViewController`.

should be initializing like this;

```
self.subViewController= [[SubViewViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SubViewViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

Answer (score 1):

change here

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewTwo animated:YES];
```

Do change in SecondViewcontroller.h file

```
{
NSString             *queryValue;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *queryValue;
```

Comment: You dont have to create instant variables anymore, an NSString property is sufficient

Comment: @YunusNedimMehel you are right but i have just formatted his code.

Answer (score 1):

You are pushing `self.subViewController` but you are passing the string to `viewTwo`. These  are 2 different objects. Use this line instead:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewTwo animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

add:
`self.subViewController = viewTwo;`

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following code

**- FirstViewcontroller:**

```
  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

        [_tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

self.subViewController = [[SubViewViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SubViewViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];


        viewTwo.queryValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row];

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.subViewController animated:YES];
    }
```

**- SecondViewcontroller.h:**

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *queryValue;
```

**- SecondViewcontroller.m:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"%@", self.queryValue);
}
```